# Secure Connection to PowerBI Online from a SQL Database in Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: sql, azure, security, powerbi, virtual-machine

I have a scenario where my customer is using their own tenant for the PowerBI Online version and I'm managing their SQL Database in my Azure Tenant/Subscription separately. The SQL Database should be exposed to the customers PowerBI Online Dashboard for Visualization purposes.

How should I establish a secure connection to a customer's PowerBI online dashboard without compromising my connection string? Technically, I don't want to open any unsecured connection to the customer with my SQL Database VM IP address publically. See the below diagram for reference. Please advise of any possible solution for this. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You'll have to use a data gateway to connect VM hosting SQL Server to the Power BI service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Azure Data Gateway can resolve this requirement. Assume the Azure VM as the on-prem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-onprem-indepth